# Get the string after the last character in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have the following string in excel cell

```
"myshop.com" "great"#12#20 Feb 2022
```

How I can get the string after the last Hash

Output

```
20 Feb 2022
```

Comment: if there is only one then use find() with right() or mid() and if there are two then use find() inside find()

Comment: the problem is that there are two #

Comment: Then as I suggested use find() inside find()... find("#",A1,find("#",A1,1)+1)

Comment: If you have Windows environment you may look into `FILTERXML`. https://stackoverflow.com/a/61837697/12634230

Comment: Sure. Give credits to JvdV in your answer. Note it only works on Windows environment.

Answer (score 2):

### Edit

**To get the string after the last character `Hash` in excel, you may try anyone of the following solutions,**

**Solution as suggested by [P.b](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12634230/p-b) --> Credit goes to [JvdV](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9758194/jvdv) Sir**

**Formula used in cell C1**

```
=FILTERXML("<a><b>"&SUBSTITUTE($A1,"#","</b><b>")&"</b></a>","//b[last()]")
```

**Solution suggested by [VBasic2008](https://stackoverflow.com/users/9814069/vbasic2008) Sir,**

**Formula used in cell D1**

```
=REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"#","@",LEN(A1)-LEN(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"#","")))),"")
```

**Solution I have posted before edit**

**Formula used in cell B1**

```
=--REPLACE(A1,1,FIND("@",SUBSTITUTE(A1,"#","@",2)),"")
```

[image: ALTERNATIVE_SOLUTIONS]

Comment: That was the whole idea, you didn't need to credit me for this, you are an excel-formula master, not me, I rarely look into it.

Comment: `FILTERXML()` is good choice for this situation.

Answer (score 1):

Another option,

In `B1`, enter formula :

```
=TRIM(RIGHT(SUBSTITUTE(A1,"#",REPT(" ",99)),99))
```

and format the result to your desired Date format

[image]